# XmlTextWriter Inheritance and Cast Exception

Tags: c#, .net, xml, inheritance, casting

I would like to create an extension of XmlTextWriter with a lot of custom methods to write down the classes and structures I use in my own file format (I don't want to use serialization because sometimes tag nesting can be very deep level so it would be quite tedious to define all the XmlElement attributes and create all the necessary projections).
Here is what I did:

```
public sealed class MySpecialWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    private static readonly XmlWriterSettings s_DefaultSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        CloseOutput = true,
        Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false),
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "\t",
        NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
    };

    public MySpecialWriter(Stream output, Encoding encoding) : base(output, encoding) { }

    public MySpecialWriter(String output, Encoding encoding) : base(output, encoding) { }

    public MySpecialWriter(TextWriter output) : base(output) { }

    public static MySpecialWriter Initialize(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        return (MySpecialWriter)Create(sb, s_DefaultSettings);
    }

    public void WriteMyClass(MyClass value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try to use it (just a simple test to see if it's working):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

try
{
    using (MySpecialWriter writer = MySpecialWriter.Initialize(sb))
    {
        writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
        writer.WriteMyClass(value)
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return null;
}

return sb.ToString();
```

I get the following exception coming from the "Initialize" method:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter' to type 'System.Xml.XmlTextWriter'.**

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
return (MySpecialWriter)Create(sb, s_DefaultSettings);
```

`Create` refers to the `XmlWriter.Create` method, which returns an instance of `XmlTextWriter`, not an instance of `MySpecialWriter`, so the cast fails. You should just use `new` to create an instance of your class.

Anyway, I don't think you really need to inherit `XmlTextWriter` here (unless you specifically need to use protected methods of `XmlTextWriter`, which is unlikely). You could probably achieve the same result by writing extension methods for `XmlWriter`.